# brew: no formula called ctls

Tags: swift, ssl, homebrew, vapor

I'm getting the following error when trying to install Vapor's CTLS package.

```
Gertrude:ctls tanner$ brew install ctls
Error: No available formula with the name "ctls" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add Vapor's tap first.

```
brew tap vapor/homebrew-tap
```

Then run it again

```
brew install ctls
```

Comment: Life saviour! Thanks